# Formatting error messages for jsonschema: how to use -F key of the validator?

Tags: jsonschema

When I run the python [jsonschema validator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) it formats error messages in a very lengthy way. It seems that first it cites the whole schema, where the error has occured, after that mentioned the problematic element and finally tells the error message itself.

If the problem is in the root schema, the resulting message become very verbose. What values do you put in `-F` key when you run the validator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that I figured it out. The formatting string to `-F` option must be in the form suitable to pass it to python [format function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). So we can use the properties of the error variable, which are listed [here](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors/).

Here is an example:

```
jsonschema hbp_prov_schema_v3.json \
-i tests/hbp_prov_example_real.json \ 
-F "ERROR: {error.path} {error.message}
"
```

This will provide a lot more readable output.